# expected type parameter `T`, found `&T in Rust

Tags: rust

How can I pass in a `Vec<T>` and compare the values contained within? I am trying to write a bubble sort function but I do not want to have to overload the function for all the possible types that could be passed in. Here is the code I have for an `i32`:

```
pub fn bubble_sort(mut arr: Vec<i32>) -> Vec<i32>
{
    for i in 1..(arr.len() - 1)
    {
        for j in 0..(arr.len() - i)
        {
            if j == arr.len() - 1 { continue; }
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]
            {
                let buffer = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = buffer;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

I tried doing:

```
pub fn bubble_sort<T>(mut arr: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>
{
    for i in 1..(arr.len() - 1)
    {
        for j in 0..(arr.len() - i)
        {
            if j == arr.len() - 1 { continue; }
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]
            {
                let buffer = &arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = &arr[j];
                arr[j] = buffer;
            }
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `>` cannot be applied to type `T`
 --> src/bubble_sort.rs:8:23
  |
8 |             if arr[j] > arr[j + 1]
  |                ------ ^ ---------- T
  |                |
  |                T
  |
help: consider restricting type parameter `T`
  |
1 | pub fn bubble_sort<T: std::cmp::PartialOrd>(mut arr: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>
  |                     ++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I tried doing that, however I then get the following error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/bubble_sort.rs:10:30
   |
1  | pub fn bubble_sort<T: std::cmp::PartialOrd>(mut arr: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T>{
   |                    - this type parameter
...
10 |                 arr[j + 1] = &arr[j];
   |                              ^^^^^^^ expected type parameter `T`, found `&T`
   |
   = note: expected type parameter `T`
                   found reference `&T`
help: consider removing the borrow
   |
10 -                 arr[j + 1] = &arr[j];
10 +                 arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
   |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try to do

```rust
let buffer = &arr[j + 1];
arr[j + 1] = &arr[j];
arr[j] = buffer;
```

what you want is to swap the elements in your array.

You can't replace an element with a reference.
As you can't just remove an element without putting something in place, and you can't copy them without constraining the type more, this isn't something as easy as it seems.

Fortunately, there's a [swap](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.swap) method, so you can do

```
arr.swap(j, j+1);
```

Now, you're moving a `Vec`. This is useless and it constrains your sort method to only vecs. I would pass a `&mut[T]` instead.

With this, your code becomes

```rust
pub fn bubble_sort<T: std::cmp::PartialOrd>(arr: &mut[T]) {
    for i in 1..(arr.len() - 1) {
        for j in 0..(arr.len() - i) {
            if j == arr.len() - 1 { continue; } // useless
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1] {
                arr.swap(j, j+1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[playground demonstration](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=132b28039c015e0a2c1ada575ad132ed)

Comment: Side note: this is outside the scope of the question but if it's for serious usage you should look at existing implementations (in Rust or not). It's usual for example to stop the external loop as soon as there's no swap, which can be checked by setting a boolean to true when you swap.

Comment: Ah, no it's just for Computer Science class

Comment: @DivineBicycle Another thing to note here: In your own code example your function _returns_ a sorted array, but also _modifies_ the passed-in array. That's not a recommended practice; a function should either leave the passed-in arguments alone and return something new, or modify the passed-in arguments but not return anything. Mixing both can lead to confusion on the caller's side.

Comment: @Lagerbaer It's better to just pass a reference to a mutable slice, but there's not problem in mutating the argument and returning it when it's moved (as it's not a reference there's no risk of confusion, the borrow checker protects against it).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can use `arr.swap()` but code still needs some changes to get working.

```rust
pub fn bubble_sort<T: std::cmp::PartialOrd>(arr: &mut Vec<T>) {
    // end of slice must be arr.len(),
    // otherwise this bubble sort won't work
    for i in 1..arr.len() { 
        for j in 0..(arr.len() - i) {
            // not needed since j can't be arr.len() - 1 in
            // line above
            // if j == arr.len() - 1 { continue; } 
            if arr[j] > arr[j + 1] {
                arr.swap(j, j + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b473a48a5e037e25adcbbf1c15e46722)

Comment: @DenysSéguret sorry, almost nothing: when I wrote this your answer was just like "use arr.swap". The only difference is commented line `if j == arr.len() - 1 { continue; }`

Comment: Can't add comment to your answer, it's quite incorrect: that bubble sort won't work ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a0d2d8aba83a40f3ccdef7d170ea1692)) since it doesn't check `i = arr.len() - 1`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the if j == arr.len() - 1 thing. That's got rid of another line!